# A person lacking money who shows off a lot

Tags: expressions, proverbs

There is a proverb in our language which is used when someone tries to show off and pretend to be very rich and also try to spend much money, and somehow prepare well-brand clothes to keep up with the wealthy elite of the society, but if you know them, you are aware that they are almost flat broke! Actually, such people boast when they have no penny to bless themselves with!
We say: "great boast, but empty pockets to buy something.

For isntance, please imagine a woman who has a lot of debts which should be paid back ASAP, but they try to buy some expensive jewellery.

Is there any current English saying to explain this situation?

Comment: I think the word *wannabe* could be used, maybe combined with something else (wannabe rich?), but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which is "your language"?

Comment: Wasn't this the intended meaning of "Gangnam style"? :)

Comment: Junior high school kids are calling them a "try-hard" and when I was a kid (80s) they were "posers".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Be aware that most people would be offended if you used any of these descriptions to them or about them.  Non-native speakers are also advised to avoid the ones marked as vulgar unless you are absolutely certain of your audience.*

We have in the UK:

- He is **all show and no substance** -- pretty much exactly the meaning you're after
- He is **all mouth and trousers** -- all talk and showy clothes [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_mouth_and_trousers)
- He is **all mouth and no trousers** -- all talk and no potency ([Guardian about which came first](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2010/aug/26/all-mouth-and-trousers-mind-your-language))
- He is **all bark and no bite** -- all talk but no power (dog metaphor)

There's a US cowboy metaphor (not necessarily universally known):

- ... **all hat and no cattle** -- [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_hat_and_no_cattle) Also **Big hat ...**

Quite a few more are in the second wiktionary ref.

Collected from comments:

- **All talk/air/gas/wind ...** (variant on *all show*, emphasising what person says), **All bling and no bullion** (*bling* showy clothes and jewellery, *bullion* solid gold), **All gilt and no gold** (*gilt* surface gold plating, *gold* solid), **all flash no cash** (*flash* display, *cash* money), **hood rich** (US, might not be understood elsewhere, looks rich but lives in a poor neighbourhood).
- With slightly different meanings: **All dollars and no sense** (US, means has money but no sense, pun on *sense* sounding same as *cents*), **All style and no substance** (looks nice but unimportant/untrustworthy/poor, could be said of a person, a film, a book, a magazine, a political party, a tool), **champagne taste on a beer budget** (unlimited variants of "expensive taste on small means", meaning wanting the rich things without having the money, but not necessarily pretending.)
- With various degrees of vulgarity and closeness to wanted phrase, also **all wind and piss** (*wind* talk, *piss* vulgar, urine = anger, but nb *to piss in the wind* = rage without effect, OED: "empty talk, bombast."), **all piss and vinegar** (OED: "orig. U.S. energy, vigour; youthful aggression", **all fur coat and no knickers** (Of a woman, orig Scottish, *fur coat* elegant on the outside, *no knickers* by avoiding necessities *or* in reality sleazy)

An antiquated but occasionally seen expression is

- He is a **penniless mountebank** -- Very dated, but occasionally seen in literary writing ("North London’s Kentish Town has always been the home of penniless artists, writers, ruffians, mountebanks and charlatans, not to mention stoners, loners and ladies of slender means." [Christopher Fowler](http://www.christopherfowler.co.uk/blog/2014/04/21/great-london-pubs-no-1-the-pineapple/) in 2014.)

Comment: These are good.  *"All show and no substance"* is also used in the US, although my feeling is that it can be used for any kind of braggadocio, not just wealth.  There's also *"he is **all talk**"*

Comment: @Andrew ... yes, though I hear a connotation of money in *substance*

Comment: Either way, it works fine for this purpose.  Although, I wouldn't recommend using "all hat and no cattle" unless you want people to think you come from Texas.  The alternate version *"Big hat; no cattle"* is even better.  :)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head @jonathanjo; "**He's all mouth and no trousers**", "**He's all show and no substance**" and  "**He's all hat and no cattle**" are pretty much exactly the meaning I was after. I just need the inquire which comstruction is more common in both AmE and BrE?

Comment: Meanwhile, I need to know whether aside from the fact that they seem to be sarcastic (although, they should be as for what they are refering to in my language), are they considered as offensive sayings too? I wonder if you let me know about Andrew's pointer! Is your last offer a sort of vulgarity or something like that?

Comment: As given in the answer, mouth/trousers is UK (OED says originally northern England); hat/cattle is US (Andrew says Texan).  You can also make up new ones very easily: all (small part), no (big part): "all coins and no notes", "all clothes and no castle"

Comment: If you said any of these directly to or of someone they are likely to be offended!  Only the trousers variations have any kind of sexual overtone, but it's mild and not vulgar.  NB these aren't sarcasm ("use of remarks that clearly mean the opposite of what they say").

Comment: My last made-up one would be **All bling and no bullion**

Comment: @A-friend  "Big hat; no cattle" would be associated with *cowboys*, who wear big hats and round up cows.  That's why I talk about Texas, because that can be said to be the center of "cowboy culture".  However, this kind of thinking exists all over the United States.   It's a great expression, but it's definitely from a regional dialect that I wouldn't use, being a "city boy" myself.

Comment: @A-friend  I think "all show and no substance" is the best answer to your question, or you could make up something like **All gilt and no gold**, or a pun like **No dollars, and no sense**

Comment: @jonathanjo  I like "penniless mountebank".  Straight out of a Victorian romance.  :)

Comment: One note: As a native US English speaker, I have never heard "all hat and no cattle". It may be a regional thing.

Comment: [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310636/common-expression-for-having-a-rich-mans-taste-but-a-poor-mans-budget) is a good reference too.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathanjo; that was a superb answer. Just I came across some other concepts. What about: "**champagne taste on a beer budget,**" or "**All flash, no cash**" and "**Hood rich**"? ;) Which one is common in this sense in AmE/BrE diallect?

Comment: Hello @Andrew. I will be happy to have your idea on my previous comment too. :)

Comment: There's also **all wind and piss**, which I used to hear more from an older generation.

Comment: Back in the day, we would say that a female who did this was "`all fur coat and no knickers`". In fact, the City of Edinburgh used to be described that way

Comment: In the vernacular in Scotland where we have a person who spends what money they have on looking like they have lots of money we would say that they were "All fur coat and no knickers" ie they spend their money on what shows rather than the essentials. They would likely live in "SPAM Valley" (the new posh housing estate) where they spent so much money on a good looking house that they cannot afford proper meals.

Comment: thanks commenters, added to answer

Answer (score 17):

I think the closest equivalent in English is the expression:

> living beyond [their] means

as in

> He should stop living **beyond his means** and start saving money.

However this is more a warning to live *within* your means, rather than a statement about someone else's *profligate* spending habits.

I've never encountered the cultural equivalent of someone who "lives rich" yet who boasts about how poor they are.  Usually someone who tries to appear rich will hide the fact that they have no money, in order to, as we say:

> keep up appearances

If someone is spending a lot in order to seem as wealthy as their friends and neighbors, we call this

> Keeping up with the Joneses

This expression doesn't mean that they have no money, rather that they are buying things they don't really need *for the sake of appearances*.  For example, Mr. Jones buys a new luxury sedan, so Mr. Smith, his neighbor, goes out and buys an even more expensive and luxurious sedan, because he wants people to believe he is wealther than Mr. Jones (even if he is not).

A less figurative term for someone who habitually spends beyond their means is

> a chronic debtor

This expression is normally used in the same kind of context as calling someone an *alcoholic*, or saying they have a *gambling problem*.  It's a label for people who should get help to overcome a serious problem in their lives.

Answer (score 13):

A common **slang** term in the US is to "**front**"

To be **"fronting"**

**Urban slang**. To put up a facade or make appearances, typically to impress or in some way deceive to maintain an image. From 'to front'.

> He is **frontin'** - that Mercedes is a rental!

In a more **formal** conversation, I would stick with the other answers given on this post. I would only use this with my friends.

Comment: This answer is correct, more or less, but not very useful.  "Front" is definitely slang in this context.  It can be difficult to use slang correctly if you are not part of the subculture that speaks that dialect (most often when you get too old for it).  Moreover, slang quickly ages past its due date.  This expression is at least 15 years old, and it's likely the kids have since come up with something to replace it.  If you tried to use it now, it's possible you would sound ... well, whatever kids nowadays say to mean "not cool".